# can't get records from sqlite in python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I try to develop Flask api for my todo app. Post requests insert a new record to 'todos' table and get requests fetching records from 'todos' table.
But when i sent get request, no records returning.

I use database extension to looking records in VS Code and inserting looks good:
[here is picture of sqlite records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK8ji.jpg)

This is my **init.py** file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import sqlite3 as sql


app = Flask('__name__')
CORS(app)
app.debug=True

db = sql.connect('todo.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        content TEXT NOT NULL
        );
    """)

from api import routes
```

And this is **route.py** files

```
from api import app, db, cursor
from flask import request
import json


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Flask-React ToDo Api"

@app.get('/api/todo')
def todo_get():
    get_data = {"content":'GET Request Accepted'}

    
    print(cursor.rowcount) #-1 returned
    
    records = cursor.fetchall()

    print(records) # empty list returned

    return json.dumps(get_data)
    # it returns dummy data for now

@app.post('/api/todo')
def todo_post():
    todo = request.get_json()
    todo = tuple(todo.values())


    db.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO todos(id,content) VALUES(?,?);
    """,todo)
    db.commit()


    return json.dumps({"data":"POST Request Accepted"})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `cursor.fetchall()` should be linked to a select statement of some sort, see [here](https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/) for examples.